# "[GraphQLError('Unknown argument "offset" on field "authors" of type "Query"" when using GraphQL offset parameter to query author table

Tags: python, django, graphql, graphene-python, graphene-django

When I use GraphQL offset to query author table, I get the error:

> [GraphQLError('Unknown argument "offset" on field "authors" of type "Query"

I booked up some website, it generally said that just use the offset parameter, it works. Could you help me find the reason?

test env: django2.1.7 + python3.6 + win7

My models.py:

```
class BaseTimeStamp(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class BaseStatus(models.Model):
    STATUS_ENABLED = 0
    STAUS_DISABLED = 1

    STATUS_CHOICE = (
        (STATUS_ENABLED, 'enabled'),
        (STAUS_DISABLED, 'disabled')
    )

    status = 
models.SmallIntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICE,default=STATUS_ENABLED)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class ModelFiltered(object):
    @staticmethod
    def get_model_field_names(cls, excludes=[], includes=[]):
        fields = list(map(lambda model_field: model_field.name , cls._meta.fields))
        filtered = list(filter(lambda field_name: field_name not in excludes, fields))
        filtered.extend(includes)
        return filtered

class Author(BaseTimeStamp, BaseStatus):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, db_index=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    @staticmethod
    def get_serialier_fields():
        return ModelFiltered.get_model_field_names(Author)

    @staticmethod
    def get_admin_display_fields():
        return ModelFiltered.get_model_field_names(Author)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created_at', )
```

My schema.py code:

```
class CountableConnectionBase(relay.Connection):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    total_count = graphene.Int()

    def resolve_total_count(self, info, **kwargs):
        return self.iterable.count()

class AuthorType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        interfaces = (relay.Node,)
        connection_class = CountableConnectionBase


class AuthorInput(graphene.InputObjectType):
    name = graphene.String(required=True)
    id = graphene.String(required=False)


class CreateAuthor(graphene.Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        author_data = AuthorInput(required=True)

    ok = graphene.Boolean()
    author = graphene.Field(AuthorType)

    def mutate(self, info, author_data):
        author = Author.objects.create(name=author_data['name'])
        ok = True
        return CreateAuthor(author=author, ok=ok)


class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    authors = DjangoConnectionField(AuthorType,
                                id=graphene.String(),
                                name=graphene.String(),

                                status=graphene.Int(),
                                orderby=graphene.String())

    def resolve_authors(self, info, **kwargs):

        orderby = kwargs.get('orderby', 'created_at')
        name = kwargs.get("name")
        if name is None:
            return Author.objects.all()
        else:
            results = Author.objects.filter(Q(name=name)).order_by(orderby)
        return results


class Mutations(graphene.ObjectType):
    create_author = CreateAuthor.Field()

schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query, mutation=Mutations)
```

My query_template:

```
query_template_str_author = '''query allauthors {{
                           authors({}) {{
                             totalCount
                             edges {{
                               node {{                                  
                                 id,
                                 name
                               }}
                               cursor
                             }}
                             pageInfo {{
                               endCursor
                               startCursor
                               hasNextPage
                               hasPreviousPage
                             }}
                          }}
                      }}'''
```

My test code:

```
params = 'first:3, offset:1'
query_str = query_template_str_author.format(params)
result = schema.execute(query_str)
self.assertEqual(result.data is not None, True)
```

Comment: According to the `schema` provided, it does not seems to have any `offset`, can you provide the api url? or the GraphQL explorer documentation?

Comment: I did't use the api url to test the problem, but I used api url for other application with <first:int, after:cusor> other than <first:int, offset:int>.